# Pandas: how to import MSLR WEB30k data?

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to work with [MSLR-WEB30k](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/mslr/) data, but I'm unfamiliar with the format of these data files.

They are .txt files, data is space-delimited, and with each vector number, a colon, and the value in each row.

Here is an example:

```
2 qid:1 1:3 2:3 3:0 4:0 5:3 6:1 7:1 8:0 9:0 10:1 11:156 12:4 13:0 14:7 15:167 16:6.931275 
17:22.076928 18:19.673353 19:22.255383 20:6.926551 21:3 22:3 23:0 24:0 25:6 26:1 27:1 28:0 29:0 
30:2 31:1 32:1 33:0 34:0 35:2 36:1 37:1 38:0 39:0 40:2 41:0 42:0 43:0 44:0 45:0 46:0.019231 
47:0.75000 48:0 49:0 50:0.035928 51:0.00641 52:0.25000 53:0 54:0 55:0.011976 56:0.00641 
57:0.25000 58:0 59:0 60:0.011976 61:0.00641 62:0.25000 63:0 64:0 65:0.011976 66:0 67:0 68:0 69:0
 70:0 71:6.931275 72:22.076928 73:0 74:0 75:13.853103 76:1.152128 77:5.99246 78:0 79:0 
80:2.297197 81:3.078917 82:8.517343 83:0 84:0 85:6.156595 86:2.310425 87:7.358976 88:0 89:0 
90:4.617701 91:0.694726 92:1.084169 93:0 94:0 95:2.78795 96:1 97:1 98:0 99:0 100:1 101:1 102:1 
103:0 104:0 105:1 106:12.941469 107:20.59276 108:0 109:0 110:16.766961 111:-18.567793 
112:-7.760072 113:-20.838749 114:-25.436074 115:-14.518523 116:-21.710022 117:-21.339609 
118:-24.497864 119:-27.690319 120:-20.203779 121:-15.449379 122:-4.474452
```

I've never run across this format before. What's this format called, and how do I get pandas to read it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Found this code on Github to process data to Pandas -
https://github.com/stiebels/letor_to_pandas_converter

```
import pandas as pd


class Letor_Converter(object):    
    '''
    Class Converter implements parsing from original letor txt files to
    pandas data frame representation.
    '''
    
    def __init__(self, path):
        
        '''
        Arguments:
            path: path to letor txt file
        '''
        self._path = path
        
    @property
    def path(self):
        return self._path
    
    @path.setter
    def path(self, p):
        self._path = p
        
    def _load_file(self):
        '''        
        Loads and parses raw letor txt file.
        
        Return:
            letor txt file parsed to csv in raw format
        '''
        return pd.read_csv(str(self._path), sep=" ", header=None)
        
    def _drop_col(self, df):
        '''
        Drops last column, which was added in the parsing procedure due to a
        trailing white space for each sample in the text file
        
        Arguments:
            df: pandas dataframe
        Return:
            df: original df with last column dropped
        '''
        return df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1)
    
    def _split_colon(self, df):
        '''
        Splits the data on the colon and transforms it into a tabular format
        where columns are features and rows samples. Cells represent feature
        values per sample.
        
        Arguments:
            df: pandas dataframe object
        Return:
            df: original df with string pattern ':' removed; columns named appropriately
        '''
        for col in range(1,len(df.columns)):
            df.loc[:,col] = df.loc[:,col].apply(lambda x: str(x).split(':')[1])
        df.columns = ['rel', 'qid'] + [str(x) for x in range(1,len(df.columns)-1)] # renaming cols
        return df
    
    def convert(self):
        '''
        Performs final conversion.
        
        Return:
            fully converted pandas dataframe
        '''
        df_raw = self._load_file()
        df_drop = self._drop_col(df_raw)
        return self._split_colon(df_drop)
    
conv = Letor_Converter("MSLR-WEB10K/Fold1/train.txt")
df_train_fold1 = conv.convert()
print (df_train_fold1.shape)
df_train_fold1.head()
```